# How to shutdown an android application?

Tags: android, shutdown

How to shutdown an android application? I don't find a shutdown command to application object.
I want to shutdown and restart in case of some critical error.

Answer (score 3):

If there is some kind of "critical error", then you should should deal with it in your code rather then trying to restart the application.

You cannot shutdown an application in Android, however once all of your Activities are closed (which you can programatically do with the Activity.finish() method), then your application is considered to be closed.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to shutdown an application, Android takes care of this.

The application is on the background and she is "freezed". If the system, or another application needs memory or CPU, Android will choose a background application to stop.

But everything is automatic. It's the Android's power !

Answer (score 1):

To terminate an activity, call `finish()`. To restart it, just call the intent again.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more in depth answer about quitting applications: [Is quitting an application frowned upon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon/2034238#2034238)

Agree with elevine on handling errors...either deal with the error and get the user back to an acceptable state or let the app force close.

Answer (score 1):

To shutdown an `activity` you can use like told by other with `finish()`. If you want to force to terminate your app including all threads and the `Application` class you can use `System.exit()`, but that had some bad favior which I forgot...